# Setting up a view controller with onboard

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

Hey guys so i'm currently using the onboard library here is a link if your unaware of it https://github.com/mamaral/Onboard

The problem is that i'm trying to use this in my view controller rather than in the app delegate, as shown in the example for this is uses the following code to setup the view controller.

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.generateSecondDemoVC()
```

But i can't seem to do this in my view controller since there is no option for this and it isn't compiling, how could i set the view controller to the method which returns the OnboardingViewController?

Here is my view controller file

```
//
//  PurchaseViewController.swift
//  News Cartel
//
//  Created by Tunde Adegoroye on 13/12/2015.
//  Copyright © 2015 Tunde Adegoroye. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Onboard

class PurchaseViewController: OnboardingViewController {

    @IBAction func closeButtonDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func loadFromNewFilters(notification: NSNotification){


    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        // Can't seem to hook it upto the viewcontroller here
        generatePurchasePaging()

    }


    func generatePurchasePaging() -> OnboardingViewController {

        let welcomePage = OnboardingContentViewController(title: "PAY WHAT YOU WANT", body: "I made my app so you could have the best experience reading tech related news. That’s why I want you to value it based on your satisfaction.", image: UIImage(named: "Purchase-Pig"), buttonText: "") { () -> Void in

        }

        let firstPurchasePage = OnboardingContentViewController(title: "MINT", body: "The app is great but there’s still a few places in room of improvement. If this is your feeling this is for you.", image: UIImage(named: "Purchase-Mint"), buttonText: "69p") { () -> Void in

        }

        let secondPurchasePage = OnboardingContentViewController(title: "SWEET", body: "IThis is the suggested price where you value the time I spent on development and design. Feel free to pay more or less.", image: UIImage(named: "Purchase-Lolly"), buttonText: "£1.49") { () -> Void in

        }

        let thirdPurchasePage = OnboardingContentViewController(title: "GOLD", body: "Hello is it me your looking for, if this popped into your mind using the app then this is the price for you.", image: UIImage(named: "Purchase-Gold"), buttonText: "£2.99") { () -> Void in

        }

        let purchaseVC = OnboardingViewController(backgroundImage: nil, contents: [welcomePage, firstPurchasePage, secondPurchasePage, thirdPurchasePage])

        return purchaseVC
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out by adding this

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    self.view.addSubview(generatePurchasePaging().view)
}
```

Comment: saved my life, they really have a poor documentation

Comment: is this still working for you? in my case, it does add it but then the onboarding is unusable

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is what you want

```
class ViewController: OnboardingViewController {

  override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
     super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

     let welcomePage = OnboardingContentViewController(title: "PAY WHAT YOU WANT", body: "I made my app so you could have the best experience reading tech related news. That’s why I want you to value it based on your satisfaction.", image: UIImage(named: "Purchase-Pig"), buttonText: "") {}
     let firstPurchasePage = OnboardingContentViewController(title: "MINT", body: "The app is great but there’s still a few places in room of improvement. If this is your feeling this is for you.", image: UIImage(named: "Purchase-Mint"), buttonText: "69p") {}
     let secondPurchasePage = OnboardingContentViewController(title: "SWEET", body: "IThis is the suggested price where you value the time I spent on development and design. Feel free to pay more or less.", image: UIImage(named: "Purchase-Lolly"), buttonText: "£1.49") {}
     let thirdPurchasePage = OnboardingContentViewController(title: "GOLD", body: "Hello is it me your looking for, if this popped into your mind using the app then this is the price for you.", image: UIImage(named: "Purchase-Gold"), buttonText: "£2.99") {}

     super.init(backgroundImage: nil, contents: [welcomePage, firstPurchasePage, secondPurchasePage, thirdPurchasePage])

     // Customize Onboard viewController
     allowSkipping = true
     skipHandler = { print("Skip") }

  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
  }

}
```

The demo on [Github](https://github.com/salimbraksa/OnboardDemo)

Comment: This is only showing the the first page isn't allow you to scroll to more than one page when you add it to the viewControllers property

Comment: That isn't what i'm asking for i want it to be scrollable with the buttons to indicate this below, the code you posted the user will need to press the buttons to move onto the next page....

Comment: Okey, I thought you just want to know how to use Onboard on a custom viewController, I'm going to continue working on what you want.

Comment: I want to copy the examples which is shown on the readme on github page basically.

Comment: I edited the code, but this change has a drawback, your custom viewController will no longer be linked to your Main Storyboard, because I was forced to call `initWithBackgroundImage:contents:` within `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`

Comment: I made some changes in the library to bring back the connexion between your viewController class and the view controller in the Storyboard.
See the demo on [Github](https://github.com/salimbraksa/OnboardDemo)